# Access object fields in a query

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, relationships

I got 3 objects, `BUnit__c, Row__c and Portfolio__c`, with the following design

```
Portfolio__c(Many)-----------(1) BUnit__c (1)-----------(Many)Row__c
```

Portfolio__c object has a lookup to the BUnit__c, Row__c and BUnit__c are Master-detail.

I want to access a field in `Portfolio__c` from a `Row__c` object query. Can I access the `Portfolio__c` object through `BUnit__c` from `Row__c` object ? Or do I have to create a lookup on `Row__c` to `Portfolio__c` ?

Comment: is this for a trigger use case or a VF controller use case?  That is, under what circumstances will you have a row (or rows) that need to fetch Portfolio? In addition, since 1 BU has many Rows and also many Portfolios, how do you known which Portfolio is the one for a given Row?

Answer (score 1):

```
set<Id> setBUIds = new  set<Id>(); //first get all the BUnit__c  ids
 for(Row__c objRow: [SELECT Id, BUnit__c  FROM Row__c ])
{
  setBUIds .add(objRow.BUnit__c );//add all BUnit__c  id into set
}
for(Portfolio__c objPortfolio: [SELECT Id, BUnit__c  FROM Portfolio__c WHERE BUnit__c IN: setBUIds ])
{
    system.debug('====objPortfolio===='+objPortfolio);
}
//now based on set of BUnit__c  ids query all the Row__c records.
```

Comment: ? OP wants to access a `Portfolio__c` from `Row__c`

Comment: @crop1645 yes, i got a current query on Row__c, so I need to access Portfolio__c from there.

Comment: @Butterfly. check above ans.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to query for your Junction object (BUnit), and get portfolio and row fields from there, using relationship fields (__r).

You would do something like the following:

```
SELECT Portolio__r.PersonName, Row__r.RowValue__c FROM BUnit__c WHERE Portfolio__c = 'portfolioId'
```

That way you will get both Row an Portfolio information querying the BUnit table.